# Is it possible to use two servers for an application

Tags: android, openfire, easyphp

I was wondering if it is possible to use two servers for an android application. I want to use a server like Openfire and another server like Easy PHP. I want to use Openfire for its messaging capabilities, but the server in itself has limitations. Its not programmable, and there are other features that need to be implemented. However, I'm not sure if using separate servers for a single app is feasible/practical? Are there any draw backs that I need to know about before I proceed?

Comment: You are making confusion about what "server" is. Openfire it's a chat server for jabber-xmpp instant messages, Easy PHP something others... Openfire it's fully programmable by plugins:
http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html . I suggest to focus more in what you need. Openfire just manage chats, you can use in combo with anything you want.

Comment: Ok, so your saying I could either create a plugin or I could use it alongside EasyPHP or Wamp Server? Just to clarify.

Comment: Wamp Server it's to deploy your website. Openfire will manage your chat. You need both if you want a website with a chat interface. If you don't want 2 server, you can deploy a JSP website on Openfire (it supports servlets) but it's tricky.

Comment: Thanks MrPk for the clarification.